# val('') removing all the values in dynamic table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a dynamic table, where one column is got from the database and another one is a dynamic field. The code is as below :

> **PHP Code**

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="tb" style='width:30%;margin-left:30%;'>
    <tbody>
        <?PHP
            $myquery=" select ROW_NUMBER,Weightage FROM Appraisal_Objectives WHERE Serial_Number like '%1153' ORDER BY Row_Number asc";
            $fetched=sqlsrv_query($conn,$myquery) ; 
            if( $fetched === false ) { die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true ));}
            while($res=sqlsrv_fetch_array($fetched,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
                $Weightage=$res['Weightage'];
                $Row_Number=$res['ROW_NUMBER'];
                    echo "<tr><td>".$Weightage."</td>";
                    echo "<td><input type='number' name='Rating[]' id='Rating' class='Rating form-control' onkeypress='return isNumberKey(event)' onChange='calc(this.parentElement.parentElement)' td>";
                    echo "<td style='display:none'><input type='number' name='max_rating[]' id='max_rating' class='max_rating form-control' onChange='calc(this.parentElement.parentElement)' value='$Weightage' td>";
                    echo "<td style='display:none'><input type='number' name='Row_Number[]' id='Row_Number' class='Row_Number form-control' value='$Row_Number' td></tr>";
            }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The data entered in **Rating** is Compared with the one entered in **Max Rating**, and if **`Rating > Max Rating`** an alert is generated. It is working fine till here. I am trying to make the value blank if the condition meets. The jQuery code is as below :

> **jQuery Code**

```
<Script>
    function isNumberKey(evt){
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
        if (charCode > 31 && (charCode != 46 &&(charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    window.calc = function (thisRow){
        var one = thisRow.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
        var rating = parseInt(one);
        var two = thisRow.getElementsByTagName('input')[1].value;
        var maxrating = parseInt(two);
        if(rating > maxrating)
        {
            alert('Your rating cannot exceed the maximum rating!');
            $(".Rating").each(function(){
            $(".Rating").val('');
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

> **Issue :**

When the Condition is met and an alert is generated, all the row values present in the table are reset instead of only that particular row. Where have I gone wrong or what have I missed? I am a complete new bee to jQuery and whatever I have done is from various sources from internet. Would appreciate any help / suggestion. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('.Rating')` - gets ALL ELEMENTS ON PAGE with this class.
you should specify you row.

try this:

```
thisRow.getElementsByClassName('Rating')[0].value = '';
```

**MORE:**
also you could try this `$(thisRow).find('.Rating').val('');`

Comment: `thisRow.getElementsByClassName('Rating').value = ''; ` this doesn't work for me surprisingly. But `$(thisRow).find('.Rating').val('');` did the trick.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName('Rating')` will return `array-like` nodelist which does not have property `value`...Correct it...

Answer (score 0):

`$('.Rating')` - is a jquery selector will selected all Rating class in whole document.

Use

```
thisRow.getElementsById('Rating').value = "";
```

Comment: By mistake i have used getElementsById instead getElementById. getElementsById selected group of matching conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is using the class selector '.Rating'.  That selects ALL elements with the class "Rating" (i.e. all your rows).

You're actually updating the value of your selection (all your rows) once for every row you have.  Kind of inefficient :)

Maybe try something more like this:

```
echo "<td><input type='number' name='Rating[]' id='Rating-row-$RowNumber' class='Rating form-control' onkeypress='return isNumberKey(event)' onChange='calc("Rating-row-$RowNumber")' td>";
```

and:

```
  if (rating > maxrating) {
    $("#"+thisRow).val('')
  }
```

}